# Can't call last_plot and grid.text inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I develop a specific theme for my company with ggplot2, where I need to adjust the plot margins, depending on the font size inside grid.text.

My idea was to create a function, where I call `last_plot()`, adjust the plot.margin and then add some `grid.text()` functions. However, somehow I cannot make this minimal code example run properly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar()

addText <- function(){
  last_plot() %+% theme(plot.margin = margin(0.30, 0, 0, 0, "npc"))
  grid.text("Something", y = unit(0.90, "npc"))
}

addText()
```

Does anyone know what the problem here is? `grid.text()` is called, but R simply ignores `last_plot() %+% theme(plot.margin = margin(0.30, 0, 0, 0, "npc"))`.

EDIT:

The problem was that `print()`was missing. Now this example works:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar()

addText <- function(){
  print(last_plot() + theme(plot.margin = margin(0.30, 0, 0, 0, "npc")))
  grid.text("Something", y = unit(0.90, "npc"))
}

addText()
```

Comment: print() is required

Comment: Indeed. That was the reason. It works!